# Arrange monitors from c++ windows application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to rearrange my monitors in extend mode with a C++ windows application, but I am struggling to find a solution.

When a monitor is connected I want to decide the position of the new monitor. (With "position" I mean if its right, left, above or below the primary monitor)

I have found a script that is activating the extend mode but it automatically orders the monitors in the last used order.
I am new to C++ and windows application thats why I can´t find a good solution.

Here is the script that activates the EXTEND mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

UINT32 PathArraySize = 0;
UINT32 ModeArraySize = 0;
DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* PathArray;
DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* ModeArray;
DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID CurrentTopology;

GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATHS, &PathArraySize, &ModeArraySize);

PathArray = (DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO*)malloc(PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));
memset(PathArray, 0, PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));

ModeArray = (DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO*)malloc(ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));
memset(ModeArray, 0, ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));

LONG ret = QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT, &PathArraySize, PathArray, &ModeArraySize, ModeArray, &CurrentTopology);
// Above CurrentTopology variable will aquire the current display setting (ie Extend, Duplicate etc)

free(PathArray);
free(ModeArray);
SetDisplayConfig(1, NULL, 0, NULL, SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND | SDC_APPLY);

}
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API to position monitors in code, that is strictly a user-defined setting in the Control Panel

Comment: @Remy Lebeau   Thanks for your reply! I hope you are wrong :-D